# How to check the format of certificate or CRL file using OpenSSL API?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm writing a piece code of code which can take both PEM and DER encoded certificates and CRL files and parse them into internal structures. Is there any way I can programmatically check the format of the input file using openSSL?

To read PEM files, `PEM_read_X509()` is used and to read DER files, `d2i_X509()` is used. I want to switch between them using an `if` condition.

---

To be more specific,

I have a CRL file, whose path is stored in a string called 'CRLFileName'.

```
crlbio = BIO_new(BIO_s_file());
if (BIO_read_filename(crlbio, CRLFileName.c_str()) <= 0)
{
        cout<<"Error loading CRL into memory."<<endl;
}

X509_CRL *crl = d2i_X509_CRL_bio(crlbio,NULL);
//if (format == FORMAT_PEM) crl=PEM_read_bio_X509_CRL(bio,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

I am looking for a function which can take in crlbio and return 'FORMAT_PEM' or 'FORMAT_DER', so that I can use the right loading function (d2i_X509_CRL_bio or PEM_read_bio_X509_CRL) based on the format.

Comment: The only way to be really sure is to try both, but as a decent heuristic DER files for cert or CRL (and most other things too) always begin with the byte 0x30 (aka char '0' in ASCII) (which is the tag for SEQUENCE+composite in DER). Note file-BIO supports seeking, though not all other BIOs do.